# Helm command in `emacsclient -c` does nothing

Tags: emacsclient, server

I am trying to bind a keyboard key for a new emacsclient frame running a specific helm command `helm-locate` like that:

`emacsclient -c --eval '(helm-locate)'`

It does not seem to work (no new frame pops-up). When I change the command (e.g. `emacsclient -c --eval '(mu4e)'`) it does work, so it must be something with the way `helm-locate` works.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried starting the daemon like this: `emacs --daemon -Q` and loading just your helm bits? I know helm works fine for me, so you'll probably need to investigate your config. Also, your changed command looks the same to me, although my eyesight is bad.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question. There was a mistake there. `--eval '(mu4e)'` works fine, `--eval '(helm-locate)'` does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had started the erroneous example from a terminal, you would have noticed output similiar to the following:

```
$ emacsclient -c --eval '(helm-locate)'
[…]
*ERROR*: Wrong number of arguments: (1 . 1), 0
```

Comparing the arguments both `mu4e` and `helm-locate` require (which can be easily found out with `M-x find-function`) reveals that while both commands are interactive, `mu4e` doesn't require any argument at all, `helm-locate` however does and is using `(interactive "P")` to tell Emacs what to fill in when used interactively.  The `P` specification supplies a raw prefix argument, so without any prefix argument it's going to be `nil`.  That's why `emacsclient -c --eval '(helm-locate nil)'` should do the trick.

If the `interactive` spec you're encountering is a lot more complex to figure out (there's an escape hatch to just use an s-expression that evaluates to a list of all arguments, it's used heavily inside Emacs itself and external packages as well), you can cheat by using `call-interactively`, then the command to execute would be `emacsclient -c --eval "(call-interactively 'helm-locate)"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Everything works fine now. I was guessing there was no need for arguments since I was calling it with a simple `M-x helm-locate`.

Comment: `M-x` is using `call-interactively` on the command it reads in, that's why.